# Chart.js in Angular 10: Specified colors not shown in multi-series bar chart (instead random colors)

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, bar-chart

I am trying to implement the stacked **bar chart** (horizontal, responsive).

I am using *Chart.js* in *Angular 10*.

It should have following specific colors for the 3 series (shown as labels in legend on top):

- **green** for `Both data`,
- **yellow** for `Only data` and
- **red** for `No data`

### Issue

However, I am getting **random colors** apart from what is being coded in `barchartColors`.

#### Actual output

This is as screenshot from the generated chart:
[image: bar chart with random colors]

#### *TypeScript*

```js
public barChartOptions: any = {
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  responsive: true
};

public barChartLabels: string[] = ['Dept1', 'Dept2', 'Dept3', 'Dept4', 'Dept5', 'Dept6'];
public barChartType = 'horizontalBar';
public barChartLegend = true;


public barChartData: any[] = [
  {data: [0, 16,4, 3, 10, 0], label: 'Both data'},
  {data: [0, 5, 0,5, 8, 0], label: 'Only data'},
  {data: [41, 6, 6,0, 48, 12], label: 'No Data'}
];

public barchartColors=[
  {backgroundColor: [
    'rgba(92, 184, 92,1)',  //green
    'rgba(255, 193, 7,1)',  //yellow
    'rgba(217, 83, 79,1)',  //red
  ]}
];
```

#### HTML

```html
<div class="card">

  <div class="card-header">
    Data Availability Department Wise
    <div class="card-header-actions">
      <a href="http://www.chartjs.org"><small class="text-muted">View</small></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-wrapper">      
       <canvas baseChart class="chart" id ="data"
         [datasets]="barChartData"
         [labels]="barChartLabels"
         [options]="barChartOptions"
         [legend]="barChartLegend"
         [colors]="barchartColors"
         [chartType]="barChartType"
       ></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Visual & Color test-report

The 3 background-colors for the data-series are shown, but in the legend on top along with the labels.

As far as I can see, they appear as coded in `barchartColors`. See my descriptions and links added to your color-specification comments:

> 'rgba(92, 184, 92  ,1)',  //green:  gives **other** [#5cb8ff](https://www.colorhexa.com/5cb8ff) color description : **Light blue**

> 'rgba(255, 193, 7  ,1)',  //yellow: gives [#ffc107](https://www.colorhexa.com/ffc107) color description : **Vivid yellow**

> 'rgba(217, 83, 79  ,1)',  //red:  gives [#d9534f](https://www.colorhexa.com/d9534f) color description : **Soft red**

Compare against your given screenshot from the generated chart:
[image: bar chart with random colors]

However:

- in the legend: they are mixed, **not assigned** correctly to the labels
- in the chart, on the bars: they are **not assigned correctly** to the series

> {data: [0, 16,4, 3, 10, 0], label: 'Both data'}, // expected Blue(Green) but was **random**

> {data: [0, 5, 0,5, 8, 0], label: 'Only data'}, // expected Yellow but was **random**

> {data: [41, 6, 6,0, 48, 12], label: 'No Data'} // expected Red but was **random**

### How to colorize Bar Datasets

Research in the *Chart.js* documentation, Bar chart's [dataset properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties) shows, that colors should be supplied **for each dataset**:

> `data.datasets[index]` - options for this dataset only

Your **datasets** are *3 series* (in JS or TypeScipt defined as 3 elements of an array). They are defined as array `barChartData` with 3 elements or JavaScript objects. Each dataset (object) is defined by properties like `data`, `label` .. but currently missing a color specification.

So you could define the desired `backgroundColor` for each dataset like this, in each object (not in a separate array!):

#### Solution

TypeScript:

```js
public barChartData: any[] = [
  {
    data: [0, 16,4, 3, 10, 0], 
    label: 'Both data',
    backgroundColor: '#5cb8ff' // LightBlue (intended: green)
  },
  {
    data: [0, 5, 0,5, 8, 0],
    label: 'Only data',
    backgroundColor: '#ffc107' // VividYellow (intended: yellow)

  },
  {
    data: [41, 6, 6,0, 48, 12],
    label: 'No Data',
    backgroundColor: '#d9534f' // SoftRed (intended: red)
  }
];
```

**Note:**

I used a **hexadecimal color notation** string (like `'#d9534f'`) as specification format. This was offered by the *Chart.js* documentation for [Colors](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html):

> You can specify the color as a string in **hexadecimal**, RGB, or HSL notations.

The same paragraph also explains why your **not-specified** (correctly) color **for the dataset** lead to apparently random colors. They were defined by defaults:

> If a color is needed, but not specified, Chart.js will use the global default color.

Then remove the `color` Angular-binding from your HTML:

```html
       <canvas baseChart class="chart" id ="data"
         [datasets]="barChartData"
         [labels]="barChartLabels"
         [options]="barChartOptions"
         [legend]="barChartLegend"

         [chartType]="barChartType"
       ></canvas>
```

### Demo

I used *Chart.js* version **3.1.1** in plain JavaScript to test it.
It worked and showed the specified colors:

[image]

**Goodie:** Even managed to add plugins that will change the **tool-tip** appearance (background-color, label's text-color).

Try the live-demo in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btco3w1p/32/).

### Further Readings

- Tutorial on *OrdinaryCoders* blog (2020): [How to use Chart.js | 11 Chart.js Examples](https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/11-chart-js-examples#charts)

  Section "Chart.js Bar Chart Example" illustrates the configuration of datasets in a bar-chart example.
- Tutorial on *Bartosz Gajda* blog (2020): [Using Angular and Chart.js to build real-time charts](https://bartoszgajda.com/2020/03/17/using-angular-and-chart-js-to-build-real-time-charts/)

  It shows how [**Ng2-Charts**](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) is used to integrate *Chart.js* with *Angular*. The `package.json` used there depends on following versions:

  ```json
  "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
  "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs it worked for me. But on hovering I get randomised colour as before.

Comment: @buddyingdev Glad the originally asked bar- & legend-colors [works for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
Even the __tooltip__ should show specified series' colors (see updated answer, section "Demo") ️.
Did you remove the `[colors]` binding from HTML?
Please post the new __tooltip issue__ in a separate question! Add there which _Chart.js_ and _Angular charts extension_ (e.g. `Ng2-Charts`) __version__ you use  ️